# How can we create a Read replica of prem Oracle server to AWS RDS (MySQL or Aurora)?

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services

I have a problem statement, where the current Oracle transaction server can't be migrated to Cloud. We want to have the most recent copy of Oracle server on Cloud but not on Oracle but on My SQL or Aurora for reporting purposes

1. If I Migrate the current Data using any migration tool, but how to replicate Delta changes into Read-Replica after the migration. Technically we Should replicate on the data which is changed since the last migration but not the entire database.

How to solve this problem any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [AWS Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). It can replicate data from on-premises databases to Amazon RDS and you can keep it running to do continuous data updates.

You will probably need to play with the schema definition a bit since you are copying data to a different database engine. The [AWS Schema Conversion Tool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/SchemaConversionTool/latest/userguide/CHAP_Welcome.html) can help with that.

Comment: Thanks, It looks like a right solution will try it out